# What's the meaning of "butt-high"?

Tags: meaning

In the text below, what does "butt-high" mean?

> "The bathroom was an olive green. The middle of the wall that led to the sink had a heating vent in it. That always came in handy when I came in from the snow because it was *butt-high*."

Can it mean "something warm"?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial attempts at research; for example, did you look up *butt* in a dictionary? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Comment: @KannE -- Only a little higher.

Comment: @HotLicks, KannE: Guys.

Comment: Grouping 2 comments together. @KannE please post an answer, "butt" (AmEng) is not a word commonly taught in language schools, and there are numerous meanings, I can see why the OP was confused. If you cannot find a definition of "butt-high" then why has this post got three votes in favour of closing? 2 of which are for lack of research. P.S I'll only upvote an answer, not a comment :)

Comment: @NigelJ But the quote doesn't use that. How could the OP possibly know what what it could be replaced with if they don't know what it means?

Comment: There's a lot here that could be explained. The slight tabooness of 'butt', its noun adjoint use, etc. The question is in earnest (I believe). It's not the best worded question but not the worst either. Too bad it was closed.

Answer (score 4):

No, it does not mean *something warm*, it means (in American colloquial speech) that the source of heat was at about the level of the writer's bottom; a convenient way to warm up when they were thoroughly chilled.

The previous sentence says that there is a vent 'in the middle of the wall'. In most adults that comes about as high as their waist or, at the same height, their butt.

It is a common pattern in informal English to describe a height as high as some other known thing, particularly part of one's anatomy. Ankle-high, knee-high, chest-high, or even the inarticulate yay-high where you gesture with your hand the approximate height.

'Butt-high'is not a common usage mostly because 'butt' is a tiny bit taboo. 'Buttocks' is the more formal way to say it, but outside of Forrest Gump, is probably only used by doctors and those who want to sound snooty. There are a number of synonyms, al with their own levels of tabooness or minced -oath sounding. Rear, rear-end, seat, derriere, ass. Of these, 'ass' is the most taboo (in the adult direction, but there's a lot worse), and 'rear' the least.

Comment: I was trying to think of the polite British word, and was having a mental blockage. But I think in this country any sales person would cop-out and call it "waist-high".

Comment: @mitch  Not sure I agree with the ethics of such a radical edit. Much rather vote to reopen the question.

Comment: @Mitch In Britain "posterior" can be used quite innocently, with a hint of mirth.